# How should I split my string using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have string which should be split on `"."` (point) and `" "` (space). I have tried:

```
s.split("[\\s\\.]")
```

but it doesn't work, because it hasn't split this string normally - `"123 456 . 11323 1"`.

How should I change my regular expression?

Comment: If you could give an input/output example, it would make the question a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a lot of blank spaces if you only split on a single character.

```
s.split("[\\s\\.]+")
```

will produce "123", "456", "11323", "1".

The `+` causes it to treat any run of spaces and dots as a single break instead of returning a string between adjacent spaces and dots.

You might still get blank strings at either end of your results since given `" 123"` it will split between the start of the string and "123".

Answer (score 3):

I think, what you want is this:

```
s.split("[\\s\\.]+");
```

Note the `+`. You don't seem to want to split on every single (!) occurrence of whitespace or dots. You want to match all lengths of combinations of whitespace or dots. That's why you have to greedy match as many as possible of those characters

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `"[\\s.]+"` as the regex.